# Why does NMaximize does not follow the constraints that were given to it?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint

(someone may want to mark it as a duplicate, but I still have to ask! I just can't figure out why!)

```
skinks = {56, 19, 28, 18, 24, 14, 9};
kskinks = 7;

myBBBlik[data_, kdata_, f0_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ, alpha_?NumericQ, beta_?NumericQ] :=

    Block[
    {K, fj, pj, loglik},
    K = kdata;
    fj = Prepend[PadRight[data, K], f0];
    pj = Table[
        PDF[MixtureDistribution[{w, 1 - w}, {BinomialDistribution[K, p], 
        BetaBinomialDistribution[alpha, beta, K]}], j],
        {j, 0, K}
    ];
    loglik = LogGamma[Tr[fj] + 1] - Tr[LogGamma[fj + 1]] + Tr[fj*Log[pj]];
    Print[loglik];
    loglik
];

pars = {f0,p,w,allpha,beta};
cons = {f0 > 0 && 0 < p < 1 && 0 < w < 1 && alpha > 0 && beta > 0};
cons2 = {f0 > 0 , 0 < p < 1 , 0 < w < 1 , alpha > 0 , beta > 0};

NMaximize[{myBBBlik[skinks, kskinks, Sequence @@ pars], cons}, pars, Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> Automatic}]
```

***Note that it may crash your kernel!***

If you take out the line `Print[loglik];`, it will give your the correct answer. Works perfect. However, if you leave it in and it may crash your kernel, but you will see something (unbelievable && unexpected) like this:
[image]

Why does it even call the function `myBBBlik`? Values like -717.752 and  -360.232 are long way from 0. These would not considered when you have `alpha>0,beta>0`. This is just really something I don't understand the way MMA works.

I am using MMA 10.0.2 X64 (win)

Comment: But usually, when the function returns a none-(real) numeric value, `NMaximize` warns me that the function is not a numeric value (or something like that). Why in this case, it does not?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. It looks like `NMinimize` is using `Quiet` internally. Probably this is a bug, but seemingly a minor one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Transferring my comment into an answer, because too many questions answered in comments makes for an untidy site...

It's because `NMinimize` handles constraints through pre- and post-processing, but the optimization algorithms it employs are basically all unconstrained methods. So, given that these have no awareness of the constraints specified and in any case are not set up to avoid producing unfeasible candidate points, one can expect that the objective function may be evaluated for some points outside the feasible region.

If this is a problem, one can rewrite the objective function to tolerate such inputs, e.g. by returning a poor result when given unsuitable values. Or, to stay strictly within the feasible region at the cost of possibly not finding the minimum, one may use (undocumented) method `"NonlinearInteriorPoint"`. Normally, this method is used anyway with constrained problems, as it serves to "polish" the result produced by another algorithm--i.e., to move it into the feasible region, if the penalty function applied to the objective function was not enough to do so by itself. (Writing a good penalty function automatically is not an easy thing to do.)

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use the `"NonlinearInteriorPoint"` method? I.e., what is the syntax for this function?

Comment: @Felix: Method -> "NonlinearInteriorPoint"